# Polymorphism, oop

Tags: oop, polymorphism, computer-science

Polymorphism describes a pattern in object oriented programming in which classes have different functionality while sharing a common interface.
In the above definition what is the meaning of common interface ?

Comment: A quick Google turns this up: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_(computer_science)

Comment: Is this better suited for Programmers Stack Exchange?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `common interface` simply means sharing the same public members.  These members are most often methods on a class, though they can also be public fields as well.  For example, if two or more classes share 3 methods with the exact same signature, they would share a common interface.

In statically typed languages like Java or C#, you can tell the compiler that two or more classes share the same interface with an 'interface' type.  In dynamically typed languages, like Javascript, as long as two or more objects share the same methods and/or fields (share an interface), they can act interchangeably without an 'interface' type.  This is knows as 'duck-typing'.